# change a flag (or just remove it)

Tags: support, flagging

I just saw an answer which was flagged as both "low quality" and "not an answer". It was a very short answer but technically correct. Thus I flagged as "invalid flags".

Afterwards I had a look at the question anyhow. And I noticed that there were other answers (given months earlier) which gave the same information. Thus this should have been flagged as "very low quality", I guess.

Is it possible to change a flag? I have not found a way to do so.

Comment: Not as far as I know, but I wouldn't worry about it. You can go downvote it if you like.

Comment: It's going to affect my number of useful flags... :-o

Comment: Those don't matter to anybody, seriously, don't worry about it.